# C# TCP client sending but not receiving messages

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp, websocket

I inherited some code for a TCP client.  It sends a message, then when complete waits for a confirmation message.  Currently it sends the message, but when it waits for the reply message it never receives it.  The `SendMessage()` method is what is called externally.

I set breakpoints and can see it hits the `Receive()` method, but never the `ReceiveCallback()`

Any help or nudge in the right direction is appreciated.

```
public class SocketService
{
    private ManualResetEvent connectDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent sendDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    private ManualResetEvent receiveDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);

    string ipAddress;
    private int portNum;
    string returnMessage;
    // private string hostName = Dns.GetHostName ();

    public SocketService(string ipAddress, int portNum)
    {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
        this.portNum = portNum;
    }

    public event Logging OnLogging;

    private void WriteLogMessage(string message)
    {
        if (this.OnLogging != null)
            this.OnLogging(message);
    }

    //char endOfLineSeparator = (char) 0x1C;
    //char cr = (char) 0x0D;
    //char vt = (char) 0x0B;

    public string SendMessage(string message)
    {
        IPAddress ip = IPAddress.Parse(this.ipAddress);
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ip, portNum);

        connectDone.Reset();

        Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
                                    SocketType.Stream,
                                    ProtocolType.Tcp);

        client.BeginConnect(remoteEP,
                            new AsyncCallback(ConnectCallback),
                            client);

        connectDone.WaitOne();

        //sendDone.Reset();

        WriteLogMessage("send message");

        Send(client, message);
        sendDone.WaitOne();

        //receiveDone.Reset();

        WriteLogMessage("receive message");

        Receive(client);
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        client.Close();

        return this.returnMessage;
    }

    private void Send(Socket client, String data)
    {
        byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

        client.BeginSend(byteData,
                        0,
                        byteData.Length,
                        0,
                        new AsyncCallback(SendCallback),
                        client);
    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);

        sendDone.Set();
    }

    private void ConnectCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;

        client.EndConnect(ar);

        connectDone.Set();
    }

    private void Receive(Socket client)
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject(client);

        client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer,
                            0,
                            StateObject.BufferSize,
                            0,
                            new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                            state);
    }

    private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.WorkSocket;

        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            state.StoredContent.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.Buffer, 0, bytesRead));

            client.BeginReceive(state.Buffer,
                                0,
                                StateObject.BufferSize,
                                0,
                                new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback),
                                state);

            WriteLogMessage(state.StoredContent.ToString());
        }
        else
        {
            this.returnMessage = state.StoredContent.ToString();

            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just comment all your `ManualResetEvent`s and try again, do you get `ReceiveCallback` invoked?

Comment: What is the definition of "message" according to the protocol you are implementing on top of TCP? How does the other side know it has received an entire message so that it knows to respond?

Comment: BTW: synchronization of callbacks is not an easy task, I would suggest to use *awaitable* *async* methods like `SendTaskAsync` ,  `ReceiveTaskAsync` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was something no one could have known.  These were HL7 messages, and there was a missing hidden character on the end of the message that was missing.  The receiving party was waiting for the message to finish sending, but without this character it never saw a complete message, thus never sent back the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SendMessage` and `Receive` functions don't actually to anything. They just send and receive bytes. They have no notion of a "message", do not mark the end of messages when sending them, nor recognize the ends of messages when receiving them. Simply put, you forgot to implement a network protocol and are assuming that TCP is a message service when it is actually a byte stream service.

If you need to send and receive messages, you have to precisely define what a "message" is and write code to send and receive them. It won't work by magic.

Comment: I'm sending a HL7 message and receiving back an ACK reply.  I know the beginning and ending characters of what I'm sending.  My assumption though was that when I open up the receive anything coming my direction will be caught by it.  Is that not the case?

Comment: As I said in the original question, I inherited this project and I don't know all the technical details of sockets.  So in the words of Sarris, "Explain as you would a child".  Please.

Answer (score 0):

As David Schwartz pointed out, you need a way of delimiting messages.

Take a look how [WebSocket data is framed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets/Writing_WebSocket_servers#Step_2.3A_Exchanging_Data_Frames).

```
0                   1                   2                   3
 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+-------------------------------+
|F|R|R|R| opcode|M| Payload len |    Extended payload length    |
|I|S|S|S|  (4)  |A|     (7)     |             (16/64)           |
|N|V|V|V|       |S|             |   (if payload len==126/127)   |
| |1|2|3|       |K|             |                               |
+-+-+-+-+-------+-+-------------+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|     Extended payload length continued, if payload len == 127  |
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +-------------------------------+
|                               |Masking-key, if MASK set to 1  |
+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+
| Masking-key (continued)       |          Payload Data         |
+-------------------------------- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
:                     Payload Data continued ...                :
+ - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - +
|                     Payload Data continued ...                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```